# Problemas de formatação com <p:columns>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou com problemas para formatar um datatable com uma coluna fixa e `x` colunas variáveis.

**POJO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="avaliaprojeto", schema="somore")
public class AvaliaProjeto implements Serializable, SampleEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idAvaliaProjeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idProjeto")
    private Projeto projeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCriterio")
    private Criterio criterio;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idEscala")
    private Escala escala;

    double valorCriterio;
//gets sets equals e hash
}
```

Existe uma lista de objetos AvaliaProjeto, várias vinculadas a um mesmo projeto. Este objeto tem como objetivo relacionar Critério-Escala. O objetivo é apresentar em um datatable no seguinte formato:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, quando insiro mais do que um projeto, a formatação é alterada para:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que são objetos AvaliaProjeto que lidam com exatamente os mesmos critérios, variando apenas seus impactos/valores.

A view utilizada para criar estes modelos e para cadastros (via diálogo) é:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags"
    template="/resources/templates/template_restrito_menuSomore_processo.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="section">
        <br />
        <center>
            <h:outputLabel value="Avaliação de Projeto" class="title" />
        </center>
        <br />

        <h:form id="form">
            <p:commandButton value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-document"
                actionListener="#{topsisBean.novoAvaliaProjeto}" process="@this"
                update="dataTable" oncomplete="PF('avaliaProjetoDialog').show()"
                class="botaoDataTable">
                <p:resetInput target="avaliaProjeto-dialog" />
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" id="btnEditar" title="Editar"
                disabled="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjeto == null}"
                class="botaoDataTable" process="@this"
                update="dataTable :form btnEditar btnExcluir"
                oncomplete="PF('avaliaProjetoDialog').show()">
                <p:resetInput target="avaliaProjeto-dialog" />
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" id="btnExcluir" title="Excluir"
                disabled="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjeto == null}"
                class="botaoDataTable" action="#{topsisBean.excluirAvaliaProjetos}"
                process="@this" update="dataTable btnExcluir btnEditar" />

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-triangle-1-w" id="btnAnterior"
                title="Etapa Anterior" disabled="#{topsisBean.pd == null}"
                class="botaoDataTable" action="criterio" process="@this"
                update="dataTable btnExcluir btnEditar" />

            <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-calculator" id="btnProximo"
                title="Calcular TOPSIS" disabled="#{topsisBean.pd == null}"
                class="botaoDataTable" action="avaliaProjeto" process="@this"
                update="dataTable btnExcluir btnEditar" />

            <p:dataTable var="p" value="#{topsisBean.getProjetosPD(true)}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" class="dataTable" id="dataTable"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma Avaliação de Projeto cadastrada"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" selection="#{topsisBean.projeto}"
                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.idProjeto}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" updtate=":form:btnExcluir" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" updtate=":form:btnExcluir" />

                <p:column headerText="Projeto">
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.nomeProjeto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:columns value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjetos}" var="ap" headerText="#{ap.criterio.nomeCriterio}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{topsisBean.verificarTipoCriterio(ap)}" />
                </p:columns>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Avaliação de Projeto"
                widgetVar="avaliaProjetoDialog" modal="true" resizable="false"
                id="avaliaProjeto-dialog" closeOnEscape="true">

                <p:messages/>

                <p:panelGrid>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column style="width:15% !important;">
                            <h:outputLabel for="pdMenu" value="Processo de Decisão: "
                                class="componentePF label bold" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column style="width:100% !important;">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="pdMenu" converter="generic"
                                value="#{topsisBean.pd}" class="componentePF text bold"
                                required="true"
                                requiredMessage="É necessário escolher um processo de decisão">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Processo"
                                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.pds}" var="pd"
                                    itemLabel="#{pd.nomePD}" itemValue="#{pd}" converter="generic" />
                                <p:ajax listener="#{topsisBean.mudouPD}"
                                    update="projetoMenu dataTableDialog" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputLabel for="projetoMenu" value="Projeto: "
                                class="componentePF label bold"
                                onclick="#{topsisBean.getProjetosPD()}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="projetoMenu" converter="generic"
                                value="#{topsisBean.projeto}"
                                class="componentePF text">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Projeto" itemDisabled="true"
                                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.projetosPD}" var="p"
                                    itemLabel="#{p.nomeProjeto}" itemValue="#{p}"
                                    converter="generic" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="2">
                            <p:dataTable var="ap" value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjetosPD}" style="width:100%; margin:0% !important;"
                                paginator="true" rows="10" class="dataTable" id="dataTableDialog"
                                emptyMessage="Nenhum Critério Cadastrado no PD #{topsisBean.pd.nomePD}" paginatorPosition="bottom">

                                <p:column headerText="Critério">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{ap.criterio.nomeCriterio}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column headerText="Valor Numérico (Se houver)" width="220">
                                    <p:spinner value="#{ap.valorCriterio}" min="0" prefix="U$D " class="componentePF text"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column id="colEscala" headerText="Escala" width="300">
                                    <p:selectOneMenu converter="generic" value="#{ap.escala}" 
                                        class="componentePF text">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Impacto de Escala" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.escalas}" var="e"
                                            itemLabel="#{e.impactoEscala}" itemValue="#{e}" converter="generic" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column colspan="2">
                            <p:commandButton value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-disk"
                                    action="#{topsisBean.cadastrarAvaliaProjetos}"
                                    id="cadastrarAvaliaProjeto" ajax="false"
                                    style="width:23% !important; float:right !important;"
                                    class="componentePF button" 
                                    rendered="#{topsisBean.pd != null}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>                
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

A montagem da tabela se dá no seguinte trecho da view supracitada:

```
<p:dataTable var="p" value="#{topsisBean.getProjetosPD(true)}"
                paginator="true" rows="10" class="dataTable" id="dataTable"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma Avaliação de Projeto cadastrada"
                paginatorPosition="bottom" selection="#{topsisBean.projeto}"
                selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{p.idProjeto}">

                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" updtate=":form:btnExcluir" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" updtate=":form:btnExcluir" />

                <p:column headerText="Projeto">
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.nomeProjeto}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:columns value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjetos}" var="ap" headerText="#{ap.criterio.nomeCriterio}">
                    <h:outputText value="#{topsisBean.verificarTipoCriterio(ap)}" />
                </p:columns>
            </p:dataTable>
```

Se precisarem de mais algo, por favor, avisem.

Comment: seu método `topsisBean.avaliaProjetos` retorna o que exatamente?

Comment: Uma lista de objetos do tipo AvaliaProjeto.

Comment: Sendo que, no caso, cada linha dessa tabela equivale a cinco registros no banco de dados. Ou seja, creio eu que o problema com duas colunas se dê pelo fato de este método retornar dez registros do banco (5 referentes a cada projeto).

Só aparecem nove devido ao fato de Projeto estar fora da <p:columns>

Comment: na verdade nesse `value` você devia retornar apenas as colunas e não a lista com os objetos, da uma olhada nesse exemplo [aqui](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columns.xhtml)

Comment: Entendi. O problema é que se eu por a lista de objetos no datatable ele vai ficar com muitas linhas indesejadas. Cada projeto tem 5 objetos avaliaProjeto. Tem alguma ideia do que possa fazer?

Comment: Se você olhar o link que eu mandei ele na verdade tem 2 listas diferentes, uma pras colunas e outra com os dados

Comment: Mas é isso. O negócio é que no meu caso são três listas. Uma (número de linhas) são os projetos, uma são as colunas e a outra são os valores das colunas. :p

Answer (score 1):

Senhores, consegui resolver o problema :D

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é o seguinte, eu usaria 3 sublistas da list de AvaliaProjeto. Uma de projetos (linhas), uma de critérios (Colunas + 1, de Projeto) e uma de Escala/ValorCritério para os valores das tuplas.

Usei o datatable com iteração nos projetos, o columns pra colunas e fiz um esquema de adiciona/deleta em um método do bean.

```
public String getValor() {
        String retorno = "";
        if( ! avaliaProjetos.isEmpty()) {
            retorno = verificarTipoCriterio(avaliaProjetos.get(0));
            avaliaProjetos.remove(0);
        }
        return retorno;
    }
```

Espero que essa informação seja útil para mais alguém. :D